# What does the word "seem" mean in these lines of Shakespeare?

Tags: meaning, william-shakespeare, othello

In Shakespeare's *Othello* 3.1.26, the Clown answers Cassio:

> She is stirring, sir; if she will stir hither, I shall seem to notify unto her.

where the verb "seem" makes me confused.

The common usage "To be suitable to" (OED IV.I) or "To have a semblance or appearance" (OED IV.II) may not befit the text here.

*The New Cambridge Shakespeare* (Edited by Norman Sanders) gives an interpretation as "to arrange", citing *A Midsummer Night's Dream* 3.1.17

> let the prologue seem to say.

But this usage is so rare that even OED does not record it.

So if Sanders is right, I may need some more quotations to support the explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the examples from *Othello* and *A Midsummer Night's Dream* cited in the question, there is at least one other example of this usage of "seem" in Shakespeare's plays. In [*The Merchant of Venice*, Act 2, scene 4](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/merchant/merchant.2.4.html), La(u)ncelot Gobbo also uses it:

> An it shall please you to break up
> this, it shall **seem** to signify.

Lancelot Gobbo's role is a clown's, just like the "Clown" in *Othello*, Act 3, scene 1, and he likes to use affected speech. His use of "seem" is an example of this (see *The Merchant of Venice*, edited by Jay L. Halio. The Oxford Shakespeare. Oxford University Press, 1993).

(For what it's worth, M. R. Ridley's edition of *Othello* for the Arden Shakespeare (Routledge, 1958, 1993) also cites Bottom's words "let the prologue seem to say" from *A Midsummer Night's Dream* as the other example of this usage.)

Comment: Thank you, in my translation I will follow Sanders' interpretation and make an annotation in which I will explain the usual usage.

Answer (score 6):

The usual interpretation of this line is that “seem” is used in the sense:

> **seem, *v.* 9b.** To think fit. *Obsolete.*
>
> <sub>*Oxford English Dictionary*.</sub>

See for example the [Bantam edition, edited by David Bevington, p. 55](https://archive.org/details/othello0000shak_n9y8/page/54/mode/2up), or the [Everyman edition, edited by John F, Andrews, p. 118](https://archive.org/details/othello00will/page/118/mode/2up). Among the *OED*’s citations for this sense is:

> *Subtle.* Beneath your threshold, bury me a load-stone
> To draw in gallants, that weare spurres: The rest,
> They'll **seeme** to follow.
>
> <sub>Ben Jonson (1616). [*The Alchemist* I.3](https://archive.org/details/workesofbeniamin00jons/page/616/mode/2up). In *The Works of Benjamin Jondon*, p. 616. London: Will Stansby.</sub>

Comment: I assume this relates to the adjective **seemly** (and opposite **unseemly**) which are still in use.